# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type when using org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer()

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, verifyerror

I would like to try on the Synchronous Kafka on https://dzone.com/articles/synchronous-kafka-using-spring-request-reply-1

However, I am hitting `java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type` when it's loading the `ConsumerFactory` Bean.

The following is my code of the `ConsumerFactory` bean:

```
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

// Default Consumer Factory
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, JSONObject> consumerFactory() {
      return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(producerConfigs(),new StringDeserializer(),new JsonDeserializer<>(JSONObject.class));
    }
```

And the following is my error in my eclipse console:

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.<init>(JsonDeserializer.java:179)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.<init>(JsonDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.beans.eai.config.WebConfig.consumerFactory(WebConfig.java:70)
15:57:53,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./eai: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ReplyingKafkaTemplate' defined in com.beans.eai.config.WebConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'replyKafkaTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'replyContainer' defined in com.beans.eai.config.WebConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'replyContainer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerFactory' defined in com.beans.eai.config.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory]: Factory method 'consumerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0
```

And the following is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "EAIDelegateBeanServiceSkeleton"

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0'
    compile "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

Not sure is it I using the wrong version of library.

I am deploying this web app in Jboss EAP 7.1, java 1.8.

Attached with my `gradle dependencies` result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.0-4
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.8.0
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:6.2.0
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0 (*)
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.3 -> 3.1.0 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)


compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.0-4
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.8.0
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:6.2.0
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0 (*)
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.3 -> 3.1.0 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.0-4
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.8.0
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:6.2.0
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0 (*)
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.3 -> 3.1.0 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

providedCompile - Additional compile classpath for libraries that should not be part of the WAR archive.
No dependencies

providedRuntime - Additional runtime classpath for libraries that should not be part of the WAR archive.
No dependencies

runtime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'runtimeOnly ' instead).
+--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.0-4
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.8.0
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:6.2.0
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0 (*)
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.3 -> 3.1.0 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.0-4
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.8.0
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:6.2.0
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0 (*)
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.3 -> 3.1.0 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testCompile - Dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testImplementation ' instead).
+--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
+--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
|    \--- junit:junit:4.10
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.0-4
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.8.0
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:6.2.0
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.10.5.1 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:6.2.0 (*)
+--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.19.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.3 -> 3.1.0 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.19.RELEASE (*)
```

Comment: Generally, this means that incompatible versions of dependencies are pulled in. Check the dependencies report to see which versions are pulled in and fix that.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, I try with gradle dependencies command, I saw that its using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5.1`, may I know how can I know its incompatible version?